# "Blind" PathFinding for fleeing agent

Tags: collision-detection, algorithm, path-finding

I know there are plenty of algorithms for finding a path from A to B. There's also a good few articles on how to avoid an enemy in a 2D space. I can't find anything on escaping from an enemy in a blind 2D space. Here's what I mean by "blind" 2D space.

1, The fleeing agent only knows its position in the grid and the enemy's position.
2, I do not know how big the grid is.
3, I do not know where the walls or obstacles are.
4, If I want to check what's directly next to me I have to "go" there, if my position changes it's an empty space, else it's a wall or an obstacle.

The goal is to avoid the chaser (enemy) for 1000 moves. I move 2x as fast therefore I get to make 1000 moves while the enemy can only make 500 (moves every 2nd turn). Furthermore I can only move in 4 directions; up, down, left, right. The enemy gets to move in diagonals too.

My first idea was to find a block or a cluster of blocks I could circle around. Well, didn't work, by the time I found one the enemy caught me. Is there a way or an article describing this problem? Would appreciate any suggestions or articles sent my way.

Comment: I'd imagine a good algorithm would depend on some  knowledge of what the map *usually* looks like. ie. not knowing the specific layout, but knowing how densely clustered obstacles tend to be, etc. If I can expect obstacles are usually small, I can feel my way around them to get to the far side from my pursuer. If on the other hand obstacles tend to be large, then I should not bother with that and instead try a different direction when I hit an obstacle, assuming I can't get around it for some distance. Do you have any such heuristics for your game environment?

Comment: Hi @DMGregory, there the game grid is always a square, however, the size is random and so is the density of obstacles. It uses a random function to pick where the obstacles (1 sqare boxes) are. Sometimes there tends to be one obstacle in a particular row, sometimes a cluster.